# Is the use of word malecha in hindu texts similar to kafir in islam and heathen in Christianity?

Tags: meaning

Is the use of word malecha in hindu texts similar to kafir in islam and heathen in Christianity?

I want to know definition of malecha from scriptures.

Also I am bit confused like malecha is a tribe or someone who denies vedas or someone who is wrong doer(mahapataka)

If malecha is a tribe. How can all tribes become malechefied?

> And without doubt the whole world will be mlecchified([Source](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03189.htm))

Comment: Mlechha is more Analogous to the Greek word 'barbarian'

Comment: The term 'mleccha' is a racial term, used to denote the shamanistic tribal groups like Shavaras, Pulindas, Kiratas etc who remained outside the pale of the civilization formulated by the Rishis. Although the term 'mleccha' does mean 'infidel/non-believer' in practical ways, usage of the word in that sense is rather recent. The term 'pakhandi/pashanda' was more popularly used to denote non-believers. However, it modern times 'pakhandi/pashanda' is adapted to denote a non-believer of Hindu ancestry, while 'mleccha' is used to denote a non-believer of non-Hindu ancestry.

Comment: This approach is similar to Judaism, who use the term 'goy' to denote a non-believer of non-Jewish origin & 'mumar' for a Jewish non-believer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Manusmriti Chapter II

> 21. That (country) which (lies) between the Himavat and the Vindhya (mountains) to the east of Prayaga and to the west of Vinasana (the place where the river Sarasvati disappears) is called Madhyadesa (the central region).

> 22. But (the tract) between those two mountains (just mentioned), which (extends) as far as the eastern and the western oceans, the wise call Aryavarta (the country of the Aryans).

> 23. That land where the black antelope naturally roams, one must know to be fit for the performance of sacrifices; **(the tract) different from that (is) the country of the Mlekkhas (barbarians)**.

As you see the inhabitants beyond the region of Aryavarta, are mlechhas. The term has a geographical connotation.

References -

1. [Manusmriti translated by George Buhler](https://saraswat-prakashan.weebly.com/manusmriti.html)

Comment: Ok, in mahabharat there is a line that whole world will be malechafied in kaliyug. So, how can land of aryavarta become land outside of aryavarta

Comment: @Hope Good point. I do not know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

India has been a target of invasions even before the Muslim invaders.

**Mleccha depredations**

> The **Mlecchas** seized the idol of Vishnu and went off.

**Linga Purana II.3.36**

Mlechhas were probably early invaders of India who did bad things. This is one possibility. I don't think the term Mleccha can be equated with kaffir or heathen.